# PHP Sessions don't carry over to the next page (Rackspace Cloud)

Tags: php, session, rackspace

I have a server on rackspace and it's needed for sessions. I've tested these exact files on another server from mediatemple and they work perfectly, but I just can't seem to get it to work on rackspace.

I've been at it for hours and I have looked at many stack overflow questions and I believe all of the answers on the rackspace knowledge base, but no luck as of yet.

Here is a live version of the problem:
http://www.dashboard.lmfaofacts.com - Page creates a session variable (id) and sets it equal to "hi".
http://www.dashboard.lmfaofacts.com/index2.php - Echos the previously set session variable..or at least it should

Index.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = "hi";
?>
<a href = "index2.php">Index2</a>
```

Index2.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>
<?php
echo session_save_path();
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['id'];
  ?>
<a href = "index.php">Index2</a>
```

It seems like session data is being written (I've found many session files in the directory in which they are stores in), however when I look at the inspector resources, I don't see a session being created, even on the main index.php page.

Any help is much appreciated. I can't for the life of me figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Have you checked that the cookie with the session id is set correctly?

Comment: Just curious, what happens if you put session_start() at the top of index2.php?

Comment: I don't believe the session id is being set at all, but how would I go about that just to be 100% sure?

Comment: As far as putting the session_start() at the top of the page, it produces the same result.

Comment: Yeah, i'm not seeing a cookie set.  You might want to check your PHP settings.  Particularly those involving cookies.

Comment: Anything specific to be looking for in cookie settings?